# How to get diagram with images as a boarder line in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, cgcontext

[image]

I drew rectangle diagram with boarder dotted blue line. I would like to rectangle diagram with same images as a boarder line. That means i want to replace dots with images

My Code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    context =UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    CGFloat dashPattern[10] = {3.0, 2.0};
    CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, dashPattern, 2);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    CGContextAddRect(context, self.bounds);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Can i set image instead of dots? Please give any suggestions to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean UIImage as an Image? Or do you mean simply png, jpeg images?

Comment: Yes @Thomas . I am searching functions like CGContextDrawTiledImage.

Comment: Ok - maybe a little worker around. You know the width / strength of your border, so i like to go that way, to splitt the border into 4 areas; left-area, right-area, top & bottom area. On ervery area you can use the `CGContextDrawTiledImage`.

Comment: You better take a look at that [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) > QuartzClipping , i think that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't try yet, but maybe you can use:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myImage].CGColor);
```